# CakePHP - passing constructor arguments to custom components

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I am trying to use a custom class in cakephp. Initially I had created a vendor class which works fine but I can't use other cakephp components.

To use built in components like $this->Text, I can create a custom component but the constructor requires a argument which is a json object returned from an API and I need to keep initializing in a loop

```
//The constructor for the class
function __construct($objValue) {
$this->messageId = $objValue['id'];
```

Is using a component suitable for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to create a component here if you don't need it in the controller scope.
also you don't need to make it a vendor class (which is third party stuff).

cake offers you a way out: Libs in `APP/Lib`
You can use them anywhere anytime.

```
App::uses('MyClassName', 'Lib');
$MyClass = new MyClassName();
```

You might even want to create a package in Lib itself - e.g. "Lib/Utility":

```
App::uses('MyClassName', 'Utility');
```

without knowing any more about what exactly this custom class does, it is difficult to be any more specific here.